# How to write a specific part of algorithm in algorithm environment in Latex?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, algpseudocode

How to exactly produce this part in the picture?
[image]

What I can do is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    
 \begin{document}
    
 \begin{algorithm}
\caption{Optimizes a convex combination of $K$ kernels and employs a linear programming solver to iteratively solve the semi-infinite linear optimization problem \eqref{eq:sonnenburg2006large-12}. 
The accuracy parameter $\varepsilon_{M K L}$ is a parameter of the algorithm.
$S_k(\alpha)$ and $c$ are determined by the cost function.
}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $S^0=1, \theta^1=-\infty, \beta_k^1=\frac{1}{K}$ for $k=1, \ldots, K$
\For{$t=1,2, \ldots$}
\State Compute $\alpha^t=\underset{\alpha \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k^t S_k(\alpha)$ by single kernel algorithm with $\mathbf{k}=\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k^t \mathbf{k}_k$
\State $S^t=\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k^t S_k^t$, where $S_k^t=S_k\left(\alpha^t\right)$
\If{$\left|1-\frac{S^t}{\theta^t}\right| \leq \varepsilon_{M K L}$} 
\State \textbf{break}
\EndIf
\State $\left(\beta^{t+1}, \theta^{t+1}\right)=\operatorname{argmax} \theta$
\State \;\;\;w.r.t.
\State \;\;\;s.t. 
\begin{align*}
  \text{w.r.t.} & \quad \beta \in \mathbb{R}^K, \theta \in \mathbb{R} \\
  \text{s.t.} & \quad \mathbf{0} \leq \beta, \quad \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k=1 \text { and } \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k S_k^r \geq \theta \text { for } r=1, \ldots, t
\end{align*}
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code working without error messages. And the question is quite unclear, because it seems your second image already shows what you want. So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score -1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Optimizes a convex combination of $K$ kernels and employs a linear programming solver to iteratively solve the semi-infinite linear optimization problem \eqref{eq:sonnenburg2006large-12}.
The accuracy parameter $\varepsilon_{M K L}$ is a parameter of the algorithm.
$S_k(\alpha)$ and $c$ are determined by the cost function.}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $S^0=1, \theta^1=-\infty, \beta_k^1=\frac{1}{K}$ for $k=1, \ldots, K$
\For{$t=1,2, \ldots$}
\State Compute $\alpha^t=\underset{\alpha \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k^t S_k(\alpha)$ by single kernel algorithm with $\mathbf{k}=\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k^t \mathbf{k}_k$
\State $S^t=\sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k^t S_k^t$, where $S_k^t=S_k\left(\alpha^t\right)$
\If{$\left|1-\frac{S^t}{\theta^t}\right| \leq \varepsilon_{M K L}$}
\State \textbf{break}
\EndIf
\State $\left(\beta^{t+1}, \theta^{t+1}\right)=\operatorname{argmax} \theta$
\begin{align*}
\text{w.r.t.} & \quad \beta \in \mathbb{R}^K, \theta \in \mathbb{R} \\
\text{s.t.} & \quad \mathbf{0} \leq \beta, \quad \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k=1 \text { and } \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k S_k^r \geq \theta \text { for } r=1, \ldots, t
\end{align*}
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]